# Lisp Flavored Erlang on Windows

Tags: erlang, lfe

Does Lisp Flavored Erlang (LFE) work on Windows? I am using LFE 0.6/Erlang 5.8.2/Windows 7 32-bit. I copied the lfe shell script as a batch file (replacing $@ with %1 %2 %3 %4) and it gives me this:

```
D:\projects\checkout\lfe>lfe
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{lfe_boot,start,[]},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that Erlang can't find the LFE ebin directory. Two ways to solve this problem are:

- Use an explicit `-pa <lfe ebin dir>` argument when starting LFE, either in the `lfe.bat` script or when you call it. Simple but hard wired.
- Use the `ERL_LIBS` environment variable. This is described in the `code` module documentation, http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html. If you create an extra Erlang library directory, say `c:\projects\erlang`, drop Erlang apps which follow the Erlang application directory structure as LFE does, and point `ERL_LIBS` at it then the code server will automatically add ebin directories it finds there to its code path.

This is also described in [How do I install LFE on Ubuntu Karmic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835942/how-do-i-install-lfe-on-ubuntu-karmic) but in a UNIX context.

The `ERL_LIBS` feature should definitely be better advertised.

**EDIT:** Replying to @Shantanu Kumar's comment.

I don't have access to a Windows machine so I can't test it properly. The problem seems to be that using `lfe_boot` tries to start the port program `ttysl` which doesn't seem to work on Windows, at least not when running `erl.exe`. Some solutions to try:

- Use `werl.exe` instead. This may work, but I would do it anyway.
- Try starting Erlang in the normal way with `werl.exe -pa ebin` (to get the right load path) and manually starting the LFE shell with `lfe_shell:server().`
- Try starting Erlang with `werl.exe -pa ebin -noshell -s lfe_shell start`. This will run `lfe_shell` as the *shell* but the `^G` won't be available.

Also while it is nice to use it you don't need to use the LFE shell to run LFE, you can use the normal Erlang shell and just call the LFE functions in the "normal" way. You might become a little schizophrenic with two io formats, but there are no problems. :-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did as suggested and got this:

C:\temp\lfe>erl -pa ebin -noshell -noinput -s lfe_boot start

=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Jan-2011::00:22:52 ===
Error in process <0.28.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{erlang,register,[user,<0.29.0>]},{user,start_port,1}]}

Comment: The second option ("werl.exe -pa bin" followed by "lfe_shell:server().") works. It also works with plain erl.exe; however, when I specify "-noinput" or "-noshell" or "-s lfe_shell start" with werl.exe or erl.exe it starts causing error.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies; I know this post is basically dead, but I don't find other posts on the topic, thus replying here seems appropriate.

I believe I've found a methodology that works.  Very simple really: just use MSYS2 and Mingw-w64 to build LFE, then run it from the build directory via ./bin/lfe.

There's one tweak needed it seems: the last line of bin/lfe seems to require a tweak to call "werl" instead of "erl".  Honestly I don't know why this is; I'm too green behind the ears with Erlang to say why.

I've also documented this with slightly more detail on my personal blog: http://www.vultaire.net/blog/2016/05/02/installing-lisp-flavored-erlang-on-windows/

Hope this helps someone out!

Comment: Yes, this way works. Thank you! I would like to add additional information about this way. I change that Makefile more than once. Plus to all actions described in the post of personal blog: 1) I replace $(BINDIR)/lfe%: to $(BINDIR)/lfe: (this is line 120 of that script file), 2)install "man" package by pacman package manager.